# How to store return value of function in a variable in react-native

Tags: react-native

I created two functions one is img(item) and second one is async get_customize_category_image(id), I call the second function in img() function where I want to pass return value of second function in img variable, I did console.log() in both functions get_customize_category_image(id) is returning correct value but in img() function is not reciving correct value img() function's log is returning {"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null} this data. How can I get same value in img() function.

Please help me with this problem.

**OLD CODE:**

```
 async get_customize_category_image(id) {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://192.168.0.3:1234/get_customize_category_image?id=' + id,
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    let img = data;
    console.log(img);
    return img;
  }

  img(item) {
    if (item.customize_category) {
      let img = this.get_customize_category_image(item.customize_category);
      console.log(img);
      return (
        <Image style={styles.profilePic} source={{uri: img}} />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Image style={styles.profilePic} source={{uri: item.featuredImage}} />
      );
    }
  }
```

**NEW CODE:**

```
    async get_customize_category_image(id) {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://192.168.0.3:1234/get_customize_category_image?id=' + id,
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    let img = data;
    // console.log(img);
    return String(img[0].image);
  }

  async img(item) {
    if (item.customize_category) {
      let img = await this.get_customize_category_image(
        item.customize_category,
      ).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      console.log(img);
      return (
        <Image style={styles.profilePic} source={{uri: item.featuredImage}} />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Image style={styles.profilePic} source={{uri: item.featuredImage}} />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    let img = '';
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <HeaderIcon />
        {this.state.loading && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="cyan" />}

        <FlatList
          onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
            if (this.isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
              this.getMorePost();
            }
          }}
          data={this.state.post}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.main}
              onPress={() => {
                this.openPost(item);
              }}>
              <View style={styles.row}>
                <View>{this.img(item)}</View> // Hear I'm calling my img() function

                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>{item.post_title}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
              <Image
                resizeMode="stretch"
                style={styles.image}
                source={{uri: item.featuredImage}}
              />
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{justifyContent: 'center', padding: 10}}
                  onPress={() => {
                    Share.share({
                      title: item.post_title,
                      message: item.post_content.replace(
                        /<[^>]*>|&nbsp;/g,
                        ' ',
                      ),
                      uri: item.featuredImage,
                    });
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../image/wlogo.png')}
                    style={{height: 45, width: 45, paddingLeft: 60}}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now the error is:

```
[Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your img(item) replace the code by :

```
img =async(item) => {
    if (item.customize_category) {
      let img = await this.get_customize_category_image(item.customize_category);
      console.log(img);
      return (
        <Image style={styles.profilePic} source={{uri: img}} />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Image style={styles.profilePic} source={{uri: item.featuredImage}} />
      );
    }
  }
```

Hope itehelps

Comment: Thanks but there is something wrong I edited my question with new code and new error, please help me with it..

Answer (score 0):

fetch return promise so it can be reject or resolved and you can access your data using then and catch like below you need to learn more basics of fetch

```
    async get_customize_category_image(id) {
    let IMAGES = [];

   await fetch(
      'http://192.168.0.3:1234/get_customize_category_image?id=' + id,
    ).then(response => {
         IMAGES = response.json();
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    });

    console.log(IMAGES)

    return IMAGES[0].image;

  }

  async img(item) {
    if (item.customize_category) {
      let img = await this.get_customize_category_image(item.customize_category)
      console.log(img);
      return (
        <Image style={styles.profilePic} source={{uri: item.featuredImage}} />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Image style={styles.profilePic} source={{uri: item.featuredImage}} />
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: 1min i am updating my answer